# Is there such a thing as a true USB over IP dongle?

Tags: usb, adapter

A lot of dongles described as "USB over IP" are really just swapping the USB style cable for UTP Cat5 cable, with at best an RJ45-to-USB straight-wire form factor adapter at each end.

What I'm looking for is a true USB over TCP/IP, where the adapters can be given IP addresses of the dongle they are "connected" to, and the USB data will route between them using normal TCP/IP.

Does such a thing exist (cheaply!) or be repurposed/adapted for it, and if so, what is it called? if not, what's the cheapest way to get something like it?

[image: Sketch]

Comment: An adapter like that would probably do better if it just used a custom protocol on Ethernet. Dunno whether it exists though.

Comment: What is the purpose of this topology? Do you want all devices on the left to appear transparently as USB devices to the block you call "server"?

Comment: I think you mean "right" not left, but yes. I can do almost everything I need, remotely with the server, no client needed, apart from physically inserting and removing USB devices, and I'd like to avoid that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need it to be a physical adapter, you can use [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) to route USB over TCP/IP.

In your picture, you'd need to install/configure software on "Server" (the client for usbip, Linux or Windows), while you'd need a Linux-computer for "Adapter 2" (the server for usbip). For the latter, a cheap one like a Raspberry Pi will do.

Comment: +1 Yep, I suspected that there could be something virtual like this, but hey, I am a hardware guy. Still trying to figure out how this would work for a standard USB stack for the comp on the left side of OP diagram. Is there any real USB there?

Comment: The problem is that to simulate an USB client attached to "Server" as in "Adapter 1", you need some kind of hardware that acts as an USB client on the one hand, but is not restricted to a particular device as most clients are, and has ethernet and is comparativily easy to program on the other hand. And that's not consumer hardware you can easily get. An embedded board with USB OTG would work. There is "man-in-the-middle" [software](https://github.com/dominicgs/USBProxy) for such boards, but you'd have to adapt it to *usbip*.

Comment: Also very useful. Thanks. Something like the Linux terminal project or a good IP KVM might handle it too

Answer (score 2):

Ok, technically you you can implement the block you call "Adapter #2", but it cannot be a simple adapter since you will need to serve the hub as a host. Therefore the "Adapter #2" must be a sort of embedded computer, with full-blown USB host service. It is called sometimes as "bridge".

Technically you can write some transport protocol across this bridge, with custom host driver, and channel USB requests and responses across. Now the problem is that if you want to utilize the standard USB stack in your server, you will need to provide low-level protocol responses within 1.7us time frame, to maintain USB framework. In essence, the trouble is that while TCP/IP protocol can tolerate very long responses to packets, the USB must receive ACKs/NAKs in 1.7us, otherwise the host will drop the port.

More, I am afraid that you will need to design a special USB controller in that Adapter-bridge, since the normal USB controller handles low level USB protocol locally in hardware, so the bridge will not have any ability to relay these responses across the Ethernet link.

In conclusion, it is practically impossible to make what you ask.

Comment: A well explained answer, its a shame though. It means USB has to stay local however its done. Well, it want ever designed for TCP adaptation